# How to fully qualified names from VBA project to object?

Tags: excel, vba, qualified-name

If I have many macro workbooks open at the same time...

Some names such as `UserForm`, `Module`, etc. overlap.
How to fully qualified names from VBA project?

for example:

```
VBAProject(ThisWorkbook.Name).UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption
MyNameOfProject(ThisWorkbook.Name).UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption
```

When the user renames the workbook, the project name remains the same...
Ideally completely avoid the workbook name, if posible?

In one workbook, for example, there is a module with a function that I would like to use from the other workbook. In general, I want things to be under control. Fully qualified as much as possible.

Comment: If you are calling a function in another workbook you need to reference its name somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to `userform` within the same work, you can just use:

From:

```
MyNameOfProject(ThisWorkbook.Name).UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption
```

To:

```
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption
```

However, for referring userform from another workbook, please avoid to do so...